# Bug: Varnish 4 install on CentOS 7 (systemctl)

Tags: linux, varnish, centos7

Installed Varnish from yum; but immediate error when initiating via systemctl.

```
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6546]: .init_func = VGC_function_vcl_init,
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6546]: .fini_func = VGC_function_vcl_fini,
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6546]: };
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6557]: Assert error in main(), mgt/mgt_main.c line 686:
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6557]: Condition((daemon(1,0)) == 0) not true.
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain varnishd[6557]: errno = 19 (No such device)
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /var/run/varnish.pid: Invalid argument
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: varnish.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish a high-perfomance HTTP accelerator.
Jul 28 14:11:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit varnish.service entered failed state.
```

SELinux is disabled; package was installed via root.  This is a fresh install.

Comment: Think I may have figured out the issue - the system needs a simple reboot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to reboot. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The message:

`Failed to read PID from file /var/run/varnish.pid Invalid argument`

is non-critical. It is just `systemd` trying to read the `pidfile` too early. You can poll status with:

```
systemctl status varnish
```

If its "Main PID" entry is matching the contents of `/var/run/varnish.pid`(and if varnishd is started via systemd, it always does), you can ignore that message. This is fixed in later versions of systemd.